# Depth First Search (Adjacency List) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, ecmascript-6, depth-first-search

I am trying to implement a DFS search and graphs. How can I make it better?

```
/**
 * Depth First Search iterative implementation
 * @param: graph to traverse and the starting node
 * @return 
 */
let DfsSearch = function(graph,startNode){
        let stack =  [];
        stack.push(startNode);

        while(stack.length >0){
            let node = stack.pop();
             console.log('visiting node',graph[node].value);
            if(graph[node].isVisited == false){

               graph[node].isVisited = true;
                for(currentNode in graph[node].edges){
                    stack.push(graph[currentNode].value); 
                }
            }

        }

}



module.exports = DfsSearch;


const  DFSSearch= require('./DFS');
/**
 * @description: outputs a new graph , in form of adjancency list 
 * inspired from https://medium.freecodecamp.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-data-structures-how-graphs-work-a223d9ef8837#.4voil9gg6 
 */
let makeGraphs = () => {
    let graph = {};

    //add vertex 
    graph.addVertex = (node) => {
        graph[node] = { edges: {} };
        graph[node].isVisited = false;
        graph[node].value = node; 
    }
    //addedges 
    graph.addEdge = (startNode, endNode) => {
        if (graph.contains(startNode) && graph.contains(endNode)) {

            graph[startNode].edges[endNode] = true;
            graph[endNode].edges[startNode] = true;
        }
    }

    //check if it contains the node
    graph.contains = (node) => {
        if (graph[node]) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    graph.removeEdge = (startNode, endNode) => {
        if (graph.contains(startNode) && graph.contains(endNode)) {
            delete graph[startNode].edges[endNode];
            delete graph[endNode].edges[startNode];
        }
    }
    graph.removeVertex = (node) => {
        if (graph.contains(node)) {
            for (connectedNodes in graph[node].edges) {
                graph.removeEdge(node,connectedNodes);
            }
        }
        delete graph[node];
    }
return graph;
}

let dfsGraph = makeGraphs();
dfsGraph.addVertex(1);
dfsGraph.addVertex(2);
dfsGraph.addVertex(3);
dfsGraph.addVertex(4);
dfsGraph.addVertex(5);
dfsGraph.addEdge(1,2);
dfsGraph.addEdge(1,3);
dfsGraph.addEdge(2,4);
dfsGraph.addEdge(2,5)
DFSSearch(dfsGraph,1);
module.exports= makeGraphs();
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use object literals

Your code currently refers to the `graph` object about 15 times. This is unnecessary, as the `graph` object is simply the eventual output of `makeGraphs`.

So, instead of creating the empty object `graph` and adding properties and methods later, you can use a single object literal declaration. Using an object literal allows you to abbreviate initialization of object properties and functions.

Where you have:

```
    let graph = {};
```

Replace with:

```
    return {
```

Then, all subsequent references to `graph` can then be removed altogether, or, in rare cases where required, replaced with `this`. Object literals also clean up the look of your other objects, such as `edges` and `nodes`.

For example, your `addVertex` function would look like this:

```
    addVertex(node) {
        this[node] = {
            edges: {},
            isVisited: false,
            value: node,
        } 
    }
```

(Note: The arrow operator is not needed because the scope is determined by the object container.)

### Handle creating edges / vertices from an array:

The part at the bottom shows how cumbersome it is to add edges and vertices one-by-one. The user would either have to write a loop or a container function. Instead, `addEdge` and `addVertex` could be easily modified to take array input. For example:

```
    addVertex(nodes) {
        for (var node in nodes) {
            this[node]: {
                edges: {},
                isVisited: false,
                value: node,
            }
        } 
    }
```

Then, to add vertices using `addVertex`:

```
dfsGraph.addVertex([1,2,3,4,5])
```